# What effect does -Xbootclasspath has on JDK core classes and when it is required?

Tags: java

I was reading about bootstrap classes from the reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html. and I am a bit confused after reading the line

> The nonstandard option, -Xbootclasspath, allows you to do so in those rare cicrcumstances in which it is necessary to use a different set of core classes.

If I want to use different set of core classes, will it append my core classes with the core class of JDK. Secondly, in what scenario is it used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, No. If you use `-Xbootclasspath`, this overrides the property `sun.boot.class.path` and you will be using core libraries available in your new classpath and not in rt.jar that is available in the distribution.

Comment: Oh! but wont it stop a developer from using core classes of jdk, if he has to use his core libraries?

Comment: Why in the world would you like to have your own core libraries. Core library include the Java platform packages and classes like (java.io.*, java.lang.*, java.util.*, sun.*, javax packages). 
If you want your own libraries to be part of your java runtime, use java extension mechanism or use application classpath which should satisfy more than 99% of use cases.

Comment: Yes I get that, but it is not clear to me when -Xbootclasspath will be needed? Any example would be helpful for my understanding

Comment: As the doc itself says it is a rare instance that you use it, but to give an example, let's if you want to use IBM JRE core libraries or JRE of some other provider.